# Having an issue with Linear Order

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here's the question:
"Let D=[0,1] x [0,1] and define ≺ on D by (a,b)≺(c,d) iff a < c, or a=c and b < d. Show that ≺ is a linear order on D. What do the segments look like?"

So, I know that I need to prove it is Reflexive, Transitive and Anti-Symmetric. I'm still very new at doing proofs. The furthest I can get is for reflexive. I believe that I would say:

(a,b) ≺ (a,b) for every (a,b)∈D.

I know the definitions of transitivity and anti-symmetric, but it's the notation that's throwing me off..

So, for Anti-Symmetric would I say:
Assume (a,b) ≺ (c,d) (iff a < c or a=c and b < d)
Assume (b,a) ≺ (d,c) (iff a < d or a=d and b < c)
then I would need to show (a,b)=(c,d)?

I'm very lost. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get your question and the definition of linear order from the same source? They use different conventions. The question is about a strict linear order (like the $<$ relation on real numbers) whereas the definition that you quoted is about non-strict linear orders (like the $\leq$ relation on real numbers). Either sort of order can be easily converted to the other sort (by adjoining or removing the pairs of the form $(x,x)$), but they are certainly not identical.